# Restrict a formula result to an int?

Tags: java, integer

I have a formula where it should be taken into account just than, when the result is an integer (not float, not double, or other number types). So....is there a possibility to say: "If the result is not an integer, than..."?

Comment: Do you have a method that returns an `int`? Then you can't have any other type of variable there... You should [edit] to show some code

Comment: `1000 * 0.001` will not necessarily yield `1.0` and be equal to 1. So: `if (Math.abs(x - Math.round(x)) < 1E-14) { intish }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(obj instanceof Integer) { 
     //this should do the job 
 }
```

Comment: Ahh, grerate, this works! Thenk you veery much.